# Minipages side by side on the right half of the page

Tags: minipage, letters, includegraphics

I have a letter format in which I would like to include two pictures only on the right half of the page - as seen below. Right now, one of the pictures is on the left half of the page, the other one is on the right.
What am I doing wrong?

[image: Example: How it should be]

```
\begin{letter}{
\makebox[\textwidth][r]{
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
%\centering
 %\raggedright
\textbf{Text} \\
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{PICTURE1.png}\\
\end{minipage}
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
%\centering
% \raggedright
\textbf{Text} \\
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{PICTURE2.png}\\
\end{minipage}
}
\end{letter}
```

Comment: The \makebox is taking up the entire width.  The \hspace{\fill} will expand the space between the pictures more than the [r].  Also, every time you end a line with { or } you are adding a space.

Comment: Please post a complete document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Which document class do you use? `letter`, `scrletter`, `scrlttr2`, ...? Moreover check out the documentation of the documentclass you are using. Most probably all the stuff that you put after `\begin{letter}` in braces will end up as the *address* in the header of the letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE. You can achieve this with a simple `\hfill` before your two minipages.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{2cm}
        Content 1
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{2cm}
        Content 2
    \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! So, if I add a third content, it is just another minipage?

Comment: Try by yourself and come back with another question if needed. You can put many minipages in a row, like above.